# Error when pressing "Up Navigation Button" on Action Bar and returning to the parent Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle

I'm relatively new to the Android world. I have an activity (*PartyActivity*) showing some info about a party. Pressing the button "Edit" it starts a new activity (*EditPartyActivity*) that allows the user to edit the info of the party. *EditPartyActivity* has an Up Navigation Button on his Action Bar that allows the user to go back to *PartyActivity* and here is my problem. When I go back to *PartyActivity* it is recreated from zero instead of resume it how it was. I would that when *PartyActivity* launches *EditPartyActivity* it stops saving his state and when I go back to *PartyActivity* from *EditPartyActivity* it not starts a new instance of *PartyActivity*, but it resumes the old *PartyActivity* that launched it. This is my code:

AndroidManifest

```
<activity
    android:name=".EditPartyActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:parentActivityName=".PartyActivity">
    <!-- Parent activity meta-data to support 4.0 and lower -->
    <meta-data 
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value=".PartyActivity" />
</activity>
```

PartyActivity

```
Intent i = new Intent(PartyActivity.this, EditPartyActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
```

There is not "finish()" after "startActivity(i)".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By specifying the parent activity name in the manifest it will always set the parent activity to be restarted.  If you don't want this you have the option to provide a different functionality for the up button as below.  Ideally you want to do this in a base activity so all your activities who need a similar back behavior do the same instead of placing below code in every activity.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home://user clicked up button
        finish();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```